# how to pass date to server using HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android

```
myphp script on server side

    <?php



     // include db connect class
     require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

     // connecting to db
     $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $tvshowname = (isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null);


    $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(imagename) VALUES ('$tvshowname')");


    $target_path1 = "http://" + "10.0.2.2/tvshow/tvshow_images/";



    //$target_path1 = "10.0.2.2/tvshow/tvshow_images/";

    //$target_path1 = 'http://10.0.2.2/tvshow/tvshow_images/';

    /* Add the original filename to our target path.
    Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
    $target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
        echo "The first file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']).
        " has been uploaded.";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        echo "target_path: " .$target_path1;
    }




    ?>


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {



            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            DataOutputStream outputStream = null;

            String pathToOurFile = UploadFilePath;

            String urlServer = "http://" + "10.0.2.2"
                    + "/tvshow/upload_tvshows.php?username=" +"niranga"+"";



            //"&tvshowchannel="+"sirasa tv"+"&tvshowtype="
            //+ "dailytelegrama" + "&tvshowdescription="+"nvnnnnnnnnnnn";



            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";

            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(

                        pathToOurFile));

                URL url = new URL(urlServer);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();



                // Allow Inputs & Outputs
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);




                // Enable POST method
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                //connection.setRequestProperty("username","niranga" );








                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        connection.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ pathToOurFile + "\"" +";username=\""+"niranga"+ lineEnd);



                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
                        // publishing the progress....
                        // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                        publishProgress("" + x);
                    }
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                        + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

                //print server response here..
                Log.e("---------",(serverResponseCode + " ===> "
                        + serverResponseMessage));

                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

            } catch (final Exception ex) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AddTVShows.this).create();

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

                Log.e("Erorrr",ex.toString());

                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage(ex.toString());


                // Setting OK Button
                alertDialog.setButton("Upload Again",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                                // closed
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",
                                //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();

                      }
                });
            }



            return null;

        }


i want to pass username parameter to serverside php script using HttpURLConnection.i use below url to do that .but username value not taking from server side php script.please help me to get username from server side php script....
```

i want to sent username value to server side php script tobe inserted to database.but it inserted null values..

String urlServer = "http://" + "10.0.2.2"
                    + "/tvshow/upload_tvshows.php?username=" +"niranga"+"";

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html

You need a make HTTP post request to the url. Also you should use Asyntask

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```